# Bixby: Unable to design layout

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I want to implement a ticket booking system for my capsule, where I need a dropbox to select ticket quantity.
Below is the design layout, which I want to implement in my capsule.
So, is it possible to implement a feature as the below image has. Or is there any alternative to implement for my capsule.
[image]
[image]
If yes, Can you please give me guidelines or examples about how to implement dropdown features along with other information.

I tried implementing using form element slider but unable to display other information using form element in a single view.

I am unable to design a layout as the above image has.
Any help on this, Please.

Answer (score 1):

The way you want to present information in an `input-view` is not feasible. The reason for this is that, while apps and websites have clicks as the primary method of user interactions, capsules are designed to be voice-first. A drop-down menu does not provide the option for a voice-based flow.

Using a `selection-of` component ([Documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/input-view.render.selection-of)) that requests the user to select one of the values would be the preferable way to go.